# Why doesn't .rstrip('\n') work?

Tags: python, line

Let's say `doc.txt` contains

```
a
b
c
d
```

and that my code is

```
f = open('doc.txt')
doc = f.read()
doc = doc.rstrip('\n')
print doc
```

why do I get the same values?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`str.rstrip()` removes the *trailing* newline, not all the newlines in the middle. You have one long string, after all.

Use [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to split your document into lines *without newlines*; you can rejoin it if you want to:

```
doclines = doc.splitlines()
doc_rejoined = ''.join(doclines)
```

but now `doc_rejoined` will have all lines running together without a delimiter.

Answer (score 7):

Because you read the whole document into one string that looks like:

```
'a\nb\nc\nd\n'
```

When you do a `rstrip('\n')` on that string, only the rightmost `\n` will be removed, leaving all the other untouched, so the string would look like:

```
'a\nb\nc\nd'
```

The solution would be to split the file into lines and then right strip every line. Or just replace all the newline characters with nothing: `s.replace('\n', '')`, which gives you `'abcd'`.

Answer (score 4):

`rstrip` strips trailing spaces from the whole string.  If you were expecting it to work on individual lines, you'd need to split the string into lines first using something like `doc.split('\n')`.

Comment: Or just `replace('\n', '')`. Line endings don't occur anywhere except at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
with open('doc.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

Explanation:

- The recommended way to open a file is using `with`, which takes care of closing the file at the end
- You can iterate over each line in the file using `for line in f`
- There's no need to call `rstrip()` now, because we're reading and printing one line at a time

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and replacing each instance of '\n' with ''. This would get rid of all the new line characters in the input text.